# Getting width of a cell in a grouped UITableView for setting section header width

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, sectionheader

Header says it all really I just need to get at the cell width of the table so I can set my section header width to be the same + a few pixels. Here is semi pseudo-code for my problem.

```
CustomHeaderView *headerView = [[CustomHeaderView alloc] init];
headerView.frame.width = [tableView getCellFrameWidth] + 10;
```

Been struggling with this all day. Getting at the width of the cells in a grouped tableview seems like it should be a trivial operation, but for some reason is not. Having said that I'm a complete beginner in IOS programming so if some of you veterans out there could explain to me why this is not trivial that would be awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:section]];

CGRect rect = cell.frame;

NSLog(@"Cell width = %f",rect.size.width);
```

Comment: this return 360 in ipad + landscape

Answer (score 4):

The Width of grouped UITableViewCell depends on table width and calculates as

```
table.frame.size.width/16.0*14.0
```

Comment: I believe it's tableView.frame.size.width/16.0*15.0

Comment: hi, do you know the default cell width of insetGrouped tableview style?

Comment: nope, I have found formula above by just running app on all possible screen sizes and analysing result.

Answer (score 1):

These things are always subject to change, but the width of a `UITableViewCell` in a grouped `UITableView` is 300.0 points and has been since iPhone OS 1.0.